# How can I fix this ValueError in One Hot Encoding?

Tags: python, data-science, data-mining

when trying to run the following code in Jupyter-Notebook, it results in the following error:

```
dataset_train.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
dataset_test.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

#One-Hot-Encoding¶
enc = OneHotEncoder()
dataset_train_categorical_values_encenc = enc.fit_transform(dataset_train_categorical_values_enc)
dataset_train_cat_data = pd.DataFrame(dataset_train_categorical_values_encenc.toarray(),columns=dumcols)
# test set
dataset_test_categorical_values_encenc = enc.fit_transform(dataset_test_categorical_values_enc)
dataset_test_cat_data = pd.DataFrame(dataset_test_categorical_values_encenc.toarray(),columns=testdumcols)
```

Error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (82332, 151), indices imply (82332, 155)

So far that is the whole code before the sheet placed above:

```
#Label Encoder

ategorical_columns=['proto', 'service', 'state']
# insert code to get a list of categorical columns into a variable, categorical_columns
categorical_columns=['proto', 'service', 'state'] 
 # Get the categorical values into a 2D numpy array
dataset_train_categorical_values = dataset_train[categorical_columns]
dataset_test_categorical_values = dataset_test[categorical_columns]

    
    #Transform categorical features into numbers using LabelEncoder()
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('BMW_Theftprotection_trainer.csv')
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('BMW_Theftprotection_tester.csv')
```

dataset_train_categorical_values_enc=dataset_train_categorical_values.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
print(dataset_train_categorical_values_enc.head())
# test set
dataset_test_categorical_values_enc=dataset_test_categorical_values.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)

```
#Dummy Columns


# protocol type
unique_protocol=sorted(dataset_train.proto.unique())
string1 = 'proto_'
unique_protocol2=[string1 + x for x in unique_protocol]
# service
unique_service=sorted(dataset_train.service.unique())
string2 = 'service_'
unique_service2=[string2 + x for x in unique_service]
# flag
unique_flag=sorted(dataset_train.state.unique())
string3 = 'state_'
unique_flag2=[string3 + x for x in unique_flag]
# put together
dumcols=unique_protocol2 + unique_service2 + unique_flag2
print(dumcols)

#do same for test set
unique_service_test=sorted(dataset_test.service.unique())
unique_service2_test=[string2 + x for x in unique_service_test]
testdumcols=unique_protocol2 + unique_service2_test + unique_flag2
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you have data values in one dataframe that do not appear in the other which will change your dimensions when one hot encoded.

Merge them before one hot encoding and then split them back up. This will give you equal column dimensions.

```py
import pandas as pd

dataframe_train = pd.DataFrame(
    {"one": ["a", "e", "i", "a", "a", "b"], "two": ["x", "x", "y", "x", "y", "y"] }, 
)
dataframe_test = pd.DataFrame(
    {"one": ["a", "e", "r"], "two": ["x", "x", "y"], },
)

train_test_df = pd.concat(
    [dataframe_test, dataframe_train],
    keys=['test','train']
).droplevel(level=1, axis=0)

ohe = pd.get_dummies(train_test_df )
test_ohe = ohe.loc['test',:].values
train_ohe = ohe.loc['train',:].values
```

I've used pandas to one hot encode here as it makes the split afterwards much easier.

Comment: Yeah indeed the train dataset has got more categories than the test dataset. How can I manage that to put the difference between those two datasets based on one category to the other?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The code above will fix the error you had by making them have the same columns. If it works and you have a follow up questions it's best to mark this as correct and ask another. If it's about the ValueError the please clarify as I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I put your code into jupyter notebook, it got me an error message and issued about the inputformat (training-dataset) which does not suit the dataframe format.

Why I do this One Hot Coding actually is to transfer the missing categories of the test dataset from the training dataset to the test dataset. I thought One Hot Coding will do the trick

Comment: You need to be clearer with the error descriptions. The word 'training-dataset' does not appear on this page and I cannot tell what line errored which makes it hard to help. Try reproducing your problem using a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way we can talk around the same code and avoid confusing moments.

Comment: Your current question is about a ValueError in One Hot Enconding. It's good practice to close this as answered and ask another one if the new question is far from the original. That way this is left as an answer for others with your first problem.

Comment: okay, thank you. I got you a thumbs up (seems not to be visible hence I got less than 15 repuatation